# Merging two skills with the same spelling but different cases on LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin

Is there any way to merge the endorsements on two skills with the same spelling but different cases on LinkedIn?

E.g. Matlab:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Somebody already chased this with their support. Check out this blog article http://logoscreative.co/linkedins-case-sensitive-skills/

LinkedIn just said:

> Unfortunately, at this time we do not have this functionality
>   available to merge skill endorsements.

Maybe it will help to bump this if you also email their support. I also encountered this issue and my choice is to keep the duplicate skills.